# Delegate method not being called

Tags: ios

I have written some methods to implement push notifications (voip pushkit) in our app.  It works perfect in an Xcode project I created to test the code.  When I copy the code into the main project some delegate methods are not exceuted...

```
import UIKit
import PushKit
import AVFoundation
import CoreData
import Meteor
import Stripe

let Meteor = METDDPClient(serverURL: NSURL(string: "http://example.com/websocket")!)


@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, PKPushRegistryDelegate {

    var voipRegistry:PKPushRegistry!
    let designAssets = DesignAssets()
    let stripePublishableKey: String = "xxxxx"
    var ringing: AVAudioPlayer!
    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

        registerForVoIPPushes()
        return true
    }



    func registerForVoIPPushes() {

        let notificationSettings: UIUserNotificationSettings! = UIApplication.sharedApplication().currentUserNotificationSettings()

        if (notificationSettings.types == UIUserNotificationType.None) {
            let notificationTypes: UIUserNotificationType = [.Badge, .Sound, .Alert]
            let notificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: notificationTypes, categories: nil)
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(notificationSettings)
        }

        voipRegistry = PKPushRegistry(queue: dispatch_get_main_queue())
        voipRegistry.delegate = self
        voipRegistry.desiredPushTypes = Set([PKPushTypeVoIP])
        print("VOIP Push registered")
    }


    func pushRegistry(registry: PKPushRegistry!, didUpdatePushCredentials credentials: PKPushCredentials!, forType type: String!) {
        let voipToken: String! = credentials.token.description
        print("\n\n##### PushKit credential: \n\n", voipToken)
    }
```

The last method (didUpdatePushCredentials) is never evaluated, the token is never printed to the console... why ?  It works perfectly fine in the test project.

Answer (score 0):

Duuuhhh, had forgotten to add the Background Modes

[image]